# Remove inoremap and cnoremap in Vim

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, vim

I was trying to map key **jk** to **Esc** key in Vim.

I didn't know about **.vimrc** at first. So I pasted these commands in vim in command mode as:

**:inoremap jk <Esc>**

**:cnoremap jk <Esc>**

Then obviously it didn't work. So I found out about **.virmc** so i pasted above commands in ~/.vimrc file and restarted the terminal. Now everytime i press **jk**, it just pastes this **<Esc>** word in the file itself.

When i search for **:inoremap jk** in command mode in vim, it says it is mapped to **<Esc>**. So if I try to remove it by **iunmap jk**, it removes it but after terminal restarts, it is back to the same problem. I don't want the keybind **jk** to paste **<Esc>** in file but want it to take me to command mode from insert mode. What am I doing wrong here? Any suggestion would help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i was in confusion with vi and vim.

inoremap and cnoremap helps in mapping key to our specific key binding.
I was having problem with vi because vim is superset of vi and this mapping doesn't seem to work in vi.

To remove **inoremap** and **cnoremap** we can do:

**iunmap <keybinding>**

**cunmap <keybinding>**

Comment: Just as a side note, it is highly likely that "vi" is just a stripped-down version of Vim on your system.